# Fancybox Gallery Loop Hiccup

Tags: jquery, fancybox, cycle, image-gallery

I am having trouble with a multiple image gallery in Fancybox. I have 4 images, 3 are hidden by CSS, one is the thumbnail. When I click on the thumbnail Fancybox launches fine and cycles through the 4 images, but when I get to the final image rather than going back to image 1 it repeats image 4 several times, then finally goes to image 1.

[You can see the phenomenon here.](http://www.pelsoh.com/beta/index4) (Click on the big white image.)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="primary">
<figure>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street_1.png" title= "1 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN
CATALOGUE</strong><br><em>216-PAGE, HARD-COVER, SMYTH-SEWN BOOK,
10.875 X 13.25 INCHES</em><br>Designed to accompany the exhibition Street Seen: The Psychological Gesture in American Photography
1940–1959 at the Milwaukee Art Museum. The exhibition focuses on the
work of six photographers, Lisette Model, Louis Faurer, Ted Croner,
Saul Leiter, William Klein, and Robert Frank during a pivital time in
American art, when global media was in its adolescence and photography
was just beginning to gain recognition in the art world."><img
src="pics/streetseen_s1.jpg" width="300" height="423"/>

<figcaption>
<h3>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</h3>
<p>Salvia lomo leggings culpa. Gluten-free enim readymade butcher, trust fund magna est food truck laboris
8-bit.</p>
<img class="nopad" src="pics/cyan_squig_long_s1.gif">
<h4> PRINT </h4>
</figcaption>
</a>
</figure> 

<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street2_s1.jpg" title="2 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN
CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street3_s1.jpg" title="3 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN
CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street4_s1.jpg" title="4 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN
CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>  
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your markup (you are missing some **>**):

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street2_s1.jpg" title="2 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street3_s1.jpg" title="3 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street4_s1.jpg" title="4 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"</a>
```

should be

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street2_s1.jpg" title="2 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street3_s1.jpg" title="3 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"></a>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="pics/street4_s1.jpg" title="4 of 4: <strong>STREET SEEN CATALOGUE</strong>"></a>
```

Comment: as far as I know, you can't add `<strong>` inside the title attribute at all